# OSGi console commands when there are multiple instances of a component

Tags: osgi

I'm using Bndtools, and I have created a component that adds OSGi console commands. I need to run multiple instances of this component (the number will be in the single digits, with each one manually configured) and I would like each instance of the component to expose its own set of commands, with its own scope. The name to use for the scope is available in the instance's configuration.

The problem is that the scope is defined using annotations, and is, of course, hard coded in the XML in OSGI-INF. I suppose I could have the component use config admin to change its own configuration, but that seems really ugly. Is there any other way to set the scope at run-time? An alternate way to do this that I'm not seeing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose the other option would be to have a single component, that gets the configuration for all of the instances, then registers each service manually, with the correct properties. That's less ugly than trying to have a component modify its own configuration, but it's really unfortunate to have to step outside DS and use the OSGi APIs directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Factory Component](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#service.component-factorycomponent) which allows you to [create component instances on demand and specify configuration properties](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#org.osgi.service.component.ComponentFactory.newInstance-Dictionary-).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I think that would have worked nicely. While waiting for an answer to this question, I came up with what I think is a better design that doesn't require this. You've given me something for my mental toolbox, however! Thanks again.